# R: For loops indented in another for loop in data frame

Tags: r, for-loop

I am new at R coding and struggling with my for loop system.
I have a data frame with the frequency of 20 zones entered as columns, and the value for each ID as rows. I want to code that for each value, if value >0, add 1 to unique visited

Here is what I coded for each zone (which takes a lot of space and time)

```
for (index in 1:length(OFTUpt$Zone1)){
  if (OFTUpt$Zone1[index]>0){
   OFTUpt$UniqueVisited[index]= OFTUpt$UniqueVisited[index]+1 
  }
}
```

Here is the code I had for the for loop, but my second for loop does not seem to have the right parameters?

```
for (i in 3:length(OFT1Upt)){
    print (OFT1Upt[i])
  for (v in length(OFT1Upt[i])){
    #here would go my =+ 1 line of code 
  }
}
```

Thank you!

EDIT: Here is the dataset. https://github.com/SoundsF1shy/Odour-cue-and-Exploration

Comment: Can you post your data? Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't the second loop be something like for (v in n:length(OFT1Upt[i])){

Comment: @jpsmith I added it as a google sheet (if that is okay)

Comment: Note that the first loop isn't necessary and can be written as a 'vectorized' calculation -- create a logical vector of relevant rows `index <- OFTUpt$Zone1 > 0` and update the UniqueVisited column `OFTUpt$UniqueVisited[index] = OFTUpt$UniqueVisited[index]+1 `

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly, you want to count all the "S" columns (S1:S20) that have a value > 0. If this is what you need to do, try the following code (that does not involve loops):

```
OFTUpt$UniqueVisited <- rowSums(OFTUpt[4:23] > 0)

head(OFTUpt)
# > head(OFTUpt)
# ID    Sex Total.Distance..cm. S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 S8 S9 S10 S11 S12 S13 S14 S15 S16 S17 S18 S19 S20 UniqueVisited
# 1  1 Female             425,096  6  7  7  6  6  4  6  4  1   5   4   4   4   3   5   3   2   4   6   5            20
# 2  2   Male             659,433 22 19 11 13 18  9  2  0  2   7   9   2   0   0   5   7   4   3   3   7            17
# 3  3 Female             804,481 15 12 10 10  6 19  4  4  2   8  21   4   4   1  10  12  11  13  11  12            20
# 4  4   Male             620,869  8  7  8 12 26  7  5  3  3   9   5   5   4   2   7   5   6   5   4   8            20
# 5  5 Female             632,211  6  4  4  4  4  8  2  1  2   4   9   2   2   3   6  21  19  14  14  14            20
# 6  6   Male             246,109  5  7  4  2  2  4  3  4  2   2   5   2   1   1   2   3   2   1   2   2            20
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was trying to achieve. It makes it so much easier.

Comment: Great! I have learned that oftentimes when I want to use a loop in R, there is some vectorized function for it that makes life easier. Good luck!